# .htaccess redirect for clean URL with parameter

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I developed a website again so I changed the urls to clean urls.

I have this old link:

- http://oriana-hospital.com/us/?lang=ar

and I want to redirect 301 to this link:

- http://oriana-hospital.com/ar/about-us

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following  in /.htaccess :

```
RewriteEngine on


RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /us/\?lang=ar [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://oriana-hospital.com/ar/about-us? [L,R]
```

Empty Question mark at the end of the destination is important as it discards the old query strings.